# PropertyValueFactory<> java

Tags: java

Tengo el sig. codigo en mi controlador de FXML:

```
package floreria;

import DB.ConexionMYSQL;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.ContextMenuEvent;
import objetos.Clientes;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

private Label label;
@FXML
private TextField txtID;
@FXML
private TextField txtNOMBRE;
@FXML
private TextField txtCORREO;
@FXML
private TextField txtDIRECCION;
@FXML
private TextField txtTELEFONO;
@FXML
private Button btnNUEVO;
@FXML
private Button btnAGREGAR;
@FXML
private Button btnELIMINAR;
@FXML
private TableView<Clientes> tablaCLIENTES;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Clientes, Long> columnaID;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Clientes, String> columnaNOMBRE;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Clientes, String> columnaCORREO;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Clientes, String> columnaDIRECCION;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Clientes, String> columnaTELEFONO;

private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    label.setText("Hello World!");
}

public ObservableList<Clientes> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private void setTable(){//asignamos los valores a las columnas
        columnaID.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<> ("id"));

        columnaNOMBRE.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<> ("nombre"));

        columnaCORREO.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<> ("correo"));

        columnaDIRECCION.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<> ("direccion"));

        columnaTELEFONO.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<> ("telefono"));

        tablaCLIENTES.setItems(data);
}


private void rellenarTabla(){
        data.clear();

        String query = ("SELECT * FROM clientes");
        ConexionMYSQL conexionMYSQL = new ConexionMYSQL();//conectamos con la base de datos
        Connection conn = conexionMYSQL.conectar();//conectamos con la base de datos

        Statement stQuery;

        try {//consulta a base de datos
            stQuery = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rsResultado;
            ResultSet ResultSet = rsResultado = stQuery.executeQuery(query);

            while (rsResultado.next()) {
                 data.add(new Clientes(Long.toString(rsResultado.getLong("id")), rsResultado.getString("nombre"), rsResultado.getString("correo"), rsResultado.getString("telefono")));

            }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    setTable();
    rellenarTabla();
}    

@FXML
private void btnNUEVO_click(ActionEvent event) {

    txtID.setDisable(true);//Autoincrementable
    txtNOMBRE.setDisable(false);
    txtDIRECCION.setDisable(false);
    txtTELEFONO.setDisable(false);
    txtCORREO.setDisable(false);

    btnNUEVO.setDisable(true);
    btnELIMINAR.setDisable(false);
    btnAGREGAR.setDisable(false);


}

@FXML
private void btnAGREGAR_click(ActionEvent event) {
    txtCORREO.setText("");
    txtDIRECCION.setText("");
    txtID.setText("");
    txtNOMBRE.setText("");
    txtTELEFONO.setText("");

    btnNUEVO.setDisable(false);
    btnELIMINAR.setDisable(true);
    btnAGREGAR.setDisable(false);

    rellenarTabla();
}

@FXML
private void btnELIMINAR_click(ActionEvent event) {
}

@FXML
private void tablaCLIENTES_contextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
}

}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me manda el sig. error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No marca ningun error en ninguna linea pero en la consola sale eso.

Answer (score 0):

[PropertyValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) es una clase genérica.

Una clase genérica es una que define uno o más placeholders para clases que se definirán en el momento de la instanciación. Por ejemplo, `java.util.ArrayList<T>` define uno, que es `T`. Cuando creas una instancia, deberías<sup>1</sup> especificar la clase por la que se sustituye: `new ArrayList<String`, por ejemplo.

A partir de Java 7 el operador diamante `<>` se puede usar para que el compilador asigne los tipos automáticamente **si los puede deducir por el contexto**. Por ejemplo

```
 ArrayList<String> miLista = new ArrayList<>();
```

Lo que falla aquí es esto, el compilador no puede deducir los tipos y protesta. Por lo tanto, tendrás que especificarlos tú en el constructor.

No conozco muy bien como funciona JavaFX o esta clase en particular, pero viendo los ejemplos parece que los tipos podrían ser : `<Clientes, String>`. En ese caso, las expresiones quedarían como:

```
columnaID.setCellFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<Clientes, String> ("id"));
```

Por supuesto, adáptalo a los tipos que de verdad quieras usar.

---

<sup>1</sup>Si no se especifica (`new ArrayList()`), es como si se especificara `Object`.